# error: class MapPane is public, should be declared in a file named MapPane.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I use this code to create map and marker but when I run it it shows blank map and errors

My code is from - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

**ContactFragment.java**

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));
    }
}
```

**fragment_contact.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.ContactFragment"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:id="@+id/contact_wrapper">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Address - 1526 Petchaburi Rd. Makkasan Rajdhevee Bangkok 10400 Thailand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Tel - +66-2652-7477-80, Fax +66-2652-7777"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

    <TextView
        android:text=" EMail - sdschool@sd.ac.th"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is error I got
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use below code .

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

 View rootView 

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.content_main);


       rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    rootView.findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

       return rootView; 

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when creating a Fragment is that you must use the onCreateView() callback to define the layout.

Comment: check here    https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html